# Swift: Twilio delegate functions not being called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, twilio

Please excuse my Swift noobiness.

I'm using Twilio's VideoCall framework and wondering why my RoomDelegate functions aren't getting called.

In my View I have an instance of RoomDelegate

```
struct AppHome: View {
    var roomDelegate = myRoomDelegate()
```

and when I connect to a room, I pass in my roomDelegate:

```
let connectOptions = ConnectOptions(token: self.accessToken) { (builder) in
    builder.roomName = self.call.call_api.room_name
    builder.audioTracks = [self.roomDelegate.localAudioTrack!]
}
let room = TwilioVideoSDK.connect(options: connectOptions, delegate: self.roomDelegate)
```

My roomDelegate class has:

```
class myRoomDelegate: NSObject, RoomDelegate {
    ...
    func roomDidConnect(room: Room) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func roomDidDisconnect(room: Room, error: Error?) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func roomDidFailToConnect(room: Room, error: Error) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func roomIsReconnecting(room: Room, error: Error) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func roomDidReconnect(room: Room) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func participantDidConnect(room: Room, participant: RemoteParticipant) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
    func participantDidDisconnect(room: Room, participant: RemoteParticipant) {
        print("Delegate " + #function)
    }
}
```

All the examples of delegation I've found use `self` so I'm trying to understand if what I'm doing is valid and if so, why aren't my delegate callbacks getting hit?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you have problem with the types so change your struct to class and try run :

```
class AppHome: View {
    var roomDelegate = myRoomDelegate()
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that'd be the case. It builds as a struct, not as a Class. But I also don't see how that'd help the problem.